# How to correctly initialize the `pFuncton` pointer

Tags: c++

How to correctly initialize the `pFuncton` pointer?

```
#include <iostream>


class CTest
{
public:
    void Function(int);
    int (*pFuncton)(int);
    void Test();
};

void CTest::Function(int Int)
{   
    std::cout << Int;
};

void CTest::Test()
{
    pFuncton = Function;
    pFuncton(1);
};

int main()
{
    CTest test;
    test.Test();
}
```

Comment: The type doesn't match. A non-static member function can't be stored in a function pointer. What is your intention here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type of the member function is `void (CTest::*pFuncton)(int);` and you need special syntax to call a member function via a member function pointer:

```
#include <iostream>


class CTest
{
public:
    void Function(int);
    void (CTest::*pFuncton)(int);
    void Test();
};

void CTest::Function(int Int)
{   
    std::cout << Int;
};

void CTest::Test()
{
    pFuncton = &CTest::Function;
    (this->*pFuncton)(1);
};

int main()
{
    CTest test;
    test.Test();
}
```

Comment: Your answer completely solved my problem. Many thanks.